# Displaying one component on the top of other

Tags: apache-flex, components

How can I display one component on the top of another one in flex without explicitly mentioning x-axis & y-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use canvas and inside canvas you can add controls that will be displayed one above another, the last one added will be the top most one and first added will stay in behind.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to consider, depending on your UI: 
This is still a bit 'hacky' (any solution for doing this will be), but given a container (VBox etc) with two or more components, set the **includeInLayout** property in the first component to **false**.  When the container renders the second component will ignore the first and draw on top.

This also would allow you to add additional components in that same container, but obviously it depends on your UI a great deal.